# Isabelle/Simpl: Calling a Procedure Twice

Tags: isabelle

I have been reading and using Isabelle/Simpl for the past month or so.  I have written and proved a few theories.  I have also written the following Isabelle/Simpl theory the illustrates the issue I currently have.

```
theory MemTest imports HeapList Vcg begin

hoarestate globals_memory =
  alloc :: "ref list"
  free :: nat

hoarestate globals_x = globals_memory +
  X :: "ref ⇒ int"

definition sz where "sz == 1::nat"

procedures (imports globals_x)
  testerX(x :: int | result :: ref) 
  "
    ´result :== NEW sz [ ´X :== 0 ];;
    ´result→´X :== ´x
  "
lemma (in testerX_impl) testerX_spec:
"
  ∀x. Γ ⊢⇩t ⦃´x = x ∧ sz ≤ ´free ⦄
             ´result :== PROC testerX(´x)
           ⦃´result ≠ Null ∧ ´result→´X = x⦄
"
  apply(vcg)
  apply(auto)
done    

procedures (imports globals_x)
  testerXcaller(Y::ref, Z::ref)
  "
    ´Y :== CALL testerX(5);;
    ´Z :== CALL testerX(2)
  "
lemma (in testerXcaller_impl) testerXcaller_spec:
  "
    ∀y z. Γ ⊢⇩t 
     ⦃ ´Y = y ∧ ´Z = z ∧ (sz + sz) ≤ ´free ⦄
     PROC testerXcaller(´Y, ´Z)
     ⦃ ´Y ≠ Null ∧ ´Z ≠ Null  ⦄
  "
  apply(vcg)
  apply(auto)
oops

end
```

Invoking procedure `testerX` twice from within procedure `testerXcaller` seems to hinder discharging the `testerXcaller_spec` lemma.  The result after application of the `vcg` and `auto` tactics is an odd subgoal which I have no clue how to discharge:

```
goal (1 subgoal):
  1. ⋀free X result x. sz + sz ≤ free ⟹ result ≠ Null ⟹ X result = 5 ⟹ sz ≤ x
```

Would anyone care to shed some light?

Cheers,
George

Answer (score 0):

Your specification of `testerX_spec` is not strong enough to propagate the size of the free space. Indeed, if you comment out it, the proof of `testerXcaller_spec` ironically goes through.

I never used Simpl, but by reading the big outline document, I found nothing on such an issue. And there is very little on `free`, so I came out with my own solution:

```
lemma (in testerX_impl) testerX_spec:
"
∀σ x.
 Γ ⊢⇩t ⦃σ. ´x = x ∧ sz ≤ ´free ⦄
         ´result :== PROC testerX(´x)
       ⦃´result ≠ Null ∧ ´result→´X = x ∧ ´result ∈ set ´alloc ∧ ´free =  ⇗σ⇖free - sz⦄
"
  apply(vcg)
  apply(auto)
done
```

that is I say the size of the free space is reduced by `sz`. The difficulty that I had -- because I am not familiar with Simpl -- was to access the state before the procedure. This is done with `σ` that needs to be universally quantified and introduced in the pre-condition.

I also add that `result` has been allocated event though it is not strictly necessary in this case, but it could be.